# Highlight stripplot points based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, stripplot

I am trying to do something like this:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# edit me
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
#sns.stripplot(data=tips, x = ['f1','f2'], y=[combined_df.r1_feature1,combined_df.r2_feature1], hue="size", palette="deep")
# wide form with x,y missing

params_anno = dict(jitter=0.25, size=5, palette="flare",
                    dodge=True)
if(value of df1 = value of df2):
    params_anno["linewidth"].append(2)
    params_anno["edgecolor"].append("green")
    
ax = sns.stripplot(data=combined_df.drop(
    "cycle_number", axis=1), **params_anno)
ax.set_ylim([0, 25])
ax.set_xlabel(xlabel="Different reads")
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel="values")
```

The if condition should determine if certain dots aka data points on the `sns.stripplot` should stand out with an edge color which makes them stand out. However, this approach above would fail because after meeting the first `True` instance, everything else afterwards would get annotated.

How should I go about it? I am unaware of how agile  `sns.stripplot(data=combined_df)` is when it comes to handling each and every data point. Is `ax.annotate` the way to do this?

I have tried using `sns.stripplot`, but the struggle lies in accessing each data point in isolation, so it can be marked differently if it meets the if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

- Conditionally separate the data with Boolean indexing in pandas, and then plot multiple stripplots to the same `axes`.

  - [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)
  - [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```py
import seaborn as sns

# load data
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# separate the data by a condition
mask = tips.total_bill.gt(20)
gt20 = tips[mask]
lt20 = tips[~mask]

# plot the dataframes in separate stripplots
ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=lt20, jitter=True, dodge=True)
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=gt20, jitter=True, dodge=True, edgecolor='r', linewidth=1, legend=None, ax=ax)

# move the legend if needed
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

### Option 2

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create a new column, `'condition'`, based on the condition, and use that for `hue=`.

```py
import seaborn as sns

# load data
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# new column based on a condition
tips = tips.assign(condition=tips.total_bill.gt(20))

# plot the stripplot with hue set to the new column
ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="condition", data=tips, jitter=True, dodge=True)

# move the legend
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

- With `dodge=False`

[image]